# ¿Qué hacen estas clases en Django?

Tags: python, django

¿Qué hace este código de Django?

[image: es Python usando framework django]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero tienes una clase BaseModel que hereda de object

despues tienes un constructor que recibe range1, range2 y range3

despues un metodo save que imprime "proceso guardado"

y despues la clase DataByGender hereda de BaseModel

en donde existe tu metodo save en el cual hace la suma de range1+range2+range3

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Amigo, por tu explicación muy buena . por decir que hace cada elemento.